# When dispelling magic of the same caster level, which order do I resolve spells?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e

Pathfinder's [*dispel magic*](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Dispel%20Magic) allows for someone to attempt to dispel one spell on someone. The process for selecting which spell is dispelled is specified.

> *Targeted Dispel:* One object, creature, or spell is the target of the *dispel magic* spell. You make one dispel check (1d20 + your caster level) and compare that to the spell with highest caster level (DC = 11 + the spell's caster level). If successful, that spell ends. If not, compare the same result to the spell with the next highest caster level. Repeat this process until you have dispelled one spell affecting the target, or you have failed to dispel every spell.

When all spells affecting the target have different caster levels the order for checking spells is clear. However, if two or more spells have the same caster level (a very likely scenario if you have a single spellcaster doing all the casting) then the algorithm becomes ambiguous. If your check is able to dispel one of multiple spells with the same caster level, **which spell gets dispelled?**

Does the caster choose? Does the target choose? Does the GM choose? Does a spell get selected at random? Do we select spells with higher spell level preferentially? Or is it completely ill-defined and players should ask their GM which ruling will be made at their table?

Comment: Huh, I thought this had been asked before.[Lots of](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpathfinder-1e%5D+dispel+magic) related questions but can't find a duplicate of this.

Comment: @Ifusaso If you can find a duplicate I'd be happy. I'm also surprised at not being able to find a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

When you dispel and there are multiple spells of the same CL which qualify, it ends up being random. You could also take the lowest DC first since that would be a lower level spell since DC generally indicates the strength of a spell.

I wasnt able to find any actual rulings on this, and without additional knowledge of all spells in effect on the target, you dont get to know, or even what spell is dispelled. Then there is also the whole casters generally dont know if their spells are still in effect unless there is an obvious indicator like say enlarge person.